# how to apply filter on one variable considering other two variable using python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, conditional-statements, tableau-api

I am having data with variables `participants`, `origin`, and `score`. And I want those participants and origin whose score is `greater than 60`. That means to filter participants I have to consider origin and score. I can filter only on origin or only on score but it will not work.

If anyone can help me, its great!!!

Comment: please share a sample of your data and the code you wrote so far

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'participants':['a','s','d'],
                   'origin':['f','g','t'],
                   'score':[7,80,9]})

print (df)
  origin participants  score
0      f            a      7
1      g            s     80
2      t            d      9

df = df[df.score > 60]
print (df)
  origin participants  score
1      g            s     80
```